# Restore-spsite...... -Force failed but deleted my site too

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I did a `Resore-SPSite`. It failed and I know the errors, but then when I try to go back to my site I couldn't find it. Checked in central admin/view all site collection, It's not there. Whats happening and how do I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restore a site collection with -Force parameter, then it will 1st delete the exisitng site collection( if that exist) then restore new site collection on that path. this is what exactly happen in your case, it first delete the site collection then try to restore but it fail. their is no roll back step in restore if it fail.

Now you can try the following thing.

- fix the error and try to restore it.
- If you want old site collection, then

  - Run get-spdeletedsite /personal/sitecollectionurl and see if you get that site collection.if yes then run the restore-spdeletedsite against that site.
  - other option is restore the Content database from the back date, recover the site collection using unattached content DB then restore it.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't able to restore the site. I had to recreate the site from scratch and restore it. The issue was my production and test environment were in different CU level.